# Python Update Issue from 2.7 to Python3 ,

Tags: 16.04

[image: Error message screenshot]

It Show this screen when I follow the process, It Usually happens with some other software

Comment: A couple of problems:  1st, it helps to cut and paste from the terminal into you question, rather than post a picture.  2nd, Ubuntu 12.04 is beyond end of life, and support for it is rather limited.

Comment: But i'm using Ubuntu 16.04 not 12.04, so how can I Solve this problem in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You tagged your system as 12.04 - All who have responded apparently read that.    Please edit your question to use a 16.04 tag (not the 12.04 tag), and as I noted earlier, copy the next from the terminal (use ctrl-C) and paste it into your question rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried this:  sudo apt install python python3

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 includes BOTH Python2 and Python3.

Critical components of the system rely upon BOTH versions of Python.
DO NOT REMOVE either version of Python.

If you already removed a version of Python, reinstall it. It won't be easy, because you probably just broke apt.

Ubuntu completed its conversion to Python3 for system components in 17.10. 17.10 and later do NOT have Python2 installed by default anymore (though it is just one apt command to install if you want it). DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE the system-provided version of Python3.

Comment: OP changed their story from 12.04 to 16.04. Thanks for the ping. Updated.